# How to make multiple preg_match

Tags: php

How do I make multiple `preg_match` on a `string`. I did a research and able to come out with below solutions.

```
<?php
$input = '@Hello@ & Good Day ~World~';
$regex = '/
    ~   
    (.*?)   
    ~
    /six';

$input_new = preg_replace($regex,'<i>$1</i>', $input);
echo $input_new;
```

the above will search for `(~)string(~)` and change to *italic* format. How do I want to make the search for `(@)string(@)` and change to ****bold**** format on the same text.

Comment: Right now you pass a string to the first and second parameter. Look up `preg_replace()` in the manual and see what else it can take as first and second parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_replace`, as the manual says, can also take more than one pattern and replacement:

```
<?php
$input = '@Hello@ & Good Day ~World~';
$regexes = array('/~(.*?)~/six',
                 '/@(.*?)@/six'
                );

$replaces = array('<i>$1</i>',
                  '<b>$1</b>'
                 );

$input_new = preg_replace($regexes, $replaces, $input);
echo $input_new;
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand how to do it!

Answer (score 1):

You do the same thing you did above, only this Time changing  *to  **and***  to  like so. Otherwise, just create a Function to do that like so:

```
    <?php

        function transposeBoldItalic($inputString, $embolden="Hello",$italicise="World"){
            $result = preg_replace("#(" . preg_quote($embolden)  . ")#", "<strong>$1</strong>", $inputString);
            $result = preg_replace("#(" . preg_quote($italicise) . ")#", "<em>$1</em>", $result);
            return $result;
        }

        // TEST IT:
        $inputString = "Hello & Good Day World";

        var_dump(transposeBoldItalic($inputString, "Hello", "World"));
        echo(transposeBoldItalic($inputString, "Hello", "World"));

        // DUMPS 
        <strong>Hello</strong> & Good Day <em>World</em>
```

Test it Here: https://eval.in/571784

Comment: Thank you for the details @Poiz

Answer (score 1):

@osnapitzkindle answer is correct, but you can also use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/([@~])(.*?)([@~])/', function ($matches){
    return (strpos($matches[1], '@') !== false) ? "<i>{$matches[2]}</i>" : "<b>{$matches[2]}</b>";}, $input
    );
```

---

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/o9pH2S)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Pedro. Will look to it